# Angular 6 select default value not working

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a select dropdown with a default selected disabled value, and a list of districts that is loaded from backend. My issue is that the dropdown never show the selected value, always show blank.

```
<form [formGroup]="districtForm">
  District:
  <select formControlName="districtControl" (change)="filterBuildings($event.target.value)" [value]='' class="form-control">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Please select district</option>
    <option *ngFor="let district of districts" [ngValue]="district">
      {{district.districtName}}
    </option>
  </select>
  <div *ngIf="errorMessageDistrict" class="text-danger">District is required
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is my ts code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { InfoService } from '../../services/info.service';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { District } from '../../models/district';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-school-switch',
  templateUrl: './school-switch.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./school-switch.component.scss']
})
export class SchoolSwitchComponent {
  districts: District[] = [];
  selectedDistrict: District;
  errorMessageDistrict;
  firstDistrict: any;
  districtForm = new FormGroup({
    districtControl: new FormControl()
  });

  constructor(
    public activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
    private infoService: InfoService,
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.infoService
      .getDistricts()
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(districts => {
        this.districts = districts;
      });
  }

  filterBuildings(filterVal: any) {
      this.selectedDistrict = this.districtForm.value.districtControl;
      //some more code
  }
```

Comment: Add ts code also

Comment: @Indrakumara done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally I create the FormGroup in the ngOnInit and then define default value in it like this :

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){
}

ngOnInit(){
      this.districtForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        districtControl: ['myDefaultValue', Validators.required]
      });
}
```

Comment: Default Option in select with value="" and included attributes selected or disabled. The dropdown won't work. Instead Use the validators. required. This works like charm.  districtControl: ['myDefaultValue', Validators.required]

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of `[value]` and instead use `[(ngModel)]` with `selectedDistrict` for `select` in your Template which would be initialized to `'none'` in the TypeScript class. Also add `[ngValue]` to the Placeholder Option. Something like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="districtForm">
  District:
  <select 
    formControlName="districtControl" 
    [(ngModel)]="selectedDistrict" 
    class="form-control">
    <option 
      [ngValue]="'none'" 
      disabled 
      selected>
      Please select district
    </option>
    <option 
      *ngFor="let district of districts" 
      [ngValue]="district">
      {{district.districtName}}
    </option>
  </select>
  <div 
    *ngIf="errorMessageDistrict" 
    class="text-danger">
    District is required
  </div>
</form>
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hrlbnu?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your reference.

Comment: It doesn't work either, besides I'm getting this warning: "It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as formControlName. Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed in Angular v7."

Comment: It worked for me..thank you...changing from value to [ngvalue] worked..

Answer (score 0):

Do not assign any default value in Form Control else your **Validators.required** will be of no use, instead use one default *option* in *select* with **value = ""** without *disabled* as shown below:

```
<form [formGroup]="districtForm">
  District:
  <select formControlName="districtControl" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select District</option>
    <option *ngFor="let district of districts" [value]="district">
      {{district.districtName}}
    </option>
  </select>
  <div *ngIf="errorMessageDistrict" class="text-danger">District is required
  </div>
</form>
```

**Form Control in Component.ts:**

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){
}

districtForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit(){
      this.createDistrictForm();
}

createDistrictForm(){
    this.districtForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        districtControl: ['', Validators.required]
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this way

```
    <select
                         
           [ngModel]="currentTimeZone"
           (change)="onSelectingValue($event)"
           #timeZone="ngModel"
                       >
                     <option *ngFor="let timeZone of allTimeZones"> 
 {{timeZone}}</option>
    </select>
```

In the Component you could have

```
allTimeZones: string = ["PST", "EST", "CT"];
currentTimeZone = "PST"
```

**When it does not work?**
If you have a value for `currentTimeZone` which is different from one of `allTimeZones`. `Example currentTimeZone = "MT" will NOT WORK`